# Getting NullReferenceException when assigning an entity to another one in EF

Tags: entity-framework-4

I'm getting the exception in the second line of the following:

```
        var proceso = procesoService.GetEntityById(_codigoProceso);
        var bitacora = new BitacoraEjecucionProceso
                           {
                               Mensaje = mensaje,
                               Fecha = DateTime.Now,
                               Resultado = resultado,
                               Proceso = proceso
                           };
```

The complete stacktrace of the exception is:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Data.Objects.EntitySetQualifiedType.GetHashCode(EntitySetQualifiedType obj)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.ContainsKey(TKey key)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.AddStateManagerTypeMetadata(EntitySet entitySet, ObjectTypeMapping mapping)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.GetOrAddStateManagerTypeMetadata(Type entityType, EntitySet entitySet)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.AddEntry(IEntityWrapper wrappedObject, EntityKey passedKey, EntitySet entitySet, String argumentName, Boolean isAdded)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.AddSingleObject(EntitySet entitySet, IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, String argumentName)
   at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.AddEntityToObjectStateManager(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean doAttach)
   at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.AddGraphToObjectStateManager(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean relationshipAlreadyExists, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
   at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.Add(IEntityWrapper wrappedTarget, Boolean applyConstraints, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean relationshipAlreadyExists, Boolean allowModifyingOtherEndOfRelationship, Boolean forceForeignKeyChanges)
   at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.Add(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean applyConstraints)
   at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference`1.set_ReferenceValue(IEntityWrapper value)
   at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference`1.set_Value(TEntity value)
   at Aseinfo.VH4.Data.BitacoraEjecucionProceso.set_Proceso(Proceso value) in C:\vh4\VH4\Data\AppDataContext.Designer.cs:line 16295
```

I've checked the EF source and have no clue why getting the hash code of my entity is throwing a NullReference..
Any ideas??

Thx!

Comment: How did you generate your entities?  Did you use the built-in templates or did you customize them somehow?  Is it possible that you overrode the default `GetHashCode()` implementation?

Comment: No, I used the autogenerated context. It seems that somehow when the Entity gets wrapped, it returns null in its EntitySet.Name or EntitySet.Container.Name....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered what was happening. My DLL was not updated because I was using external CSDL, SSDL and MSL files.